# Subtract one table value to another table value to another table value in PLSQL Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

*I want to (Add `p.L_VALUE` AND `p.I_VALUE` And with this result, Subtract `c.con_value`) subtract one column to another column in different table, the function below compiles successfully but the subtract result is not correct:*

```
function CF_OP_QTYFormula return Number is 
   V_QTY number(10); 
begin 
  select sum(nvl(p.L_QTY, 0)) + sum(nvl(p.I_QTY, 0)) - sum(nvl(c.CON_QTY,0)) 
    into V_QTY 
    from raw_purchase p, raw_consum c 
   where p.ITEMCODE = c.ITEMCODE 
     and p.ITEMCODE = :ITEMCODE 
     and p.MONTH_YEAR between '31-MAY-2010' 
     and ADD_MONTHS(:date1, -1); 
    return v_qty; 
  exception when no_data_found then return null; 
end;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
function CF_OP_QTYFormula( i_ITEMCODE raw_purchase.ITEMCODE%type, i_date1 date ) return Number is 
   V_QTY number(10); 
begin 
  select sum(nvl(p.L_QTY, 0) + nvl(p.I_QTY, 0) - nvl(c.CON_QTY,0)) 
    into V_QTY 
    from raw_purchase p, raw_consum c 
   where p.ITEMCODE = c.ITEMCODE 
     and p.ITEMCODE = i_ITEMCODE 
     and p.MONTH_YEAR between to_date('31.05.2010','dd.mm.rrrr') and ADD_MONTHS(i_date1, -1); 
    return v_qty; 
  exception when no_data_found then return null; 
end;
```